# How to check LVM mirroring under Linux?

Tags: lvm

How can I check the LVM mirroring under Linux? E.g.: are there any mirrors on a given machine & some details about them, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lvs | fgrep "mwi"
```

"m" means: mirrored

Comment: and with this I could be 100% sure that it's not mirrored in any way (on the server)?

Answer (score 2):

This is an old thread but if useful to anyone, to monitor current LVM raids an mirror one can use as previously expressed lvs.

The first and the 7th value of Attributes respones can be used to monitor raids or mirror. In the first case::

```
lvs | grep "r.....r"
```

Can detect mirrors or raid types.
To detect anomalities you can use the 9th attr... volume health:

```
lvs | grep "r.....r.[prm]"
```

Would detect partial, mistmatch or refresh status.

Answer (score 1):

The commands `pvdisplay`, `vgdisplay` and `lvdisplay` will show you the configured physical volumes, volume groups and logical volumes respectively of the LVM subsystem on a machine. `mdadm` will give you information about the configured raid subsystem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this too:

```
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities :
unused devices: <none>
```

It means you don't have mirror or  any RAID configuration in your system.

Comment: How does software RAID relate to LVM?